# Multiple Mongo Templates: how to use it?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I need to use multiple mongo templates to connect to several mondo databases.
First, I realized one:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MongoConfiguration {

    private final MongoDictionariesProperties mongoDictionariesProperties;
    
    @Bean(name = "mongoDictionaryTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate mongoDictionaryTemplate() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(mongoDictionariesProperties.getHost());
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, mongoDictionariesProperties.getDatabase());
    }
}
```

Okay, it works. Than, I realized second:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MongoConfiguration {

    private final MongoDictionariesProperties mongoDictionariesProperties;
    private final MongoCountersProperties mongoCountersProperties;

    @Bean(name = "mongoDictionaryTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate mongoDictionaryTemplate() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(mongoDictionariesProperties.getHost());
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, mongoDictionariesProperties.getDatabase());
    }

    @Bean(name = "mongoCountersTemplate")
    public MongoTemplate mongoCountersTemplate() {
        ConnectionString connectionString = new ConnectionString(mongoCountersProperties.getHost());
        MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(connectionString)
                .build();
        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(mongoClientSettings);
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoClient, mongoCountersProperties.getDatabase());
    }
}
```

Than, I have 2 different beans. When I run app, I get exception:

> Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'gridFsTemplate' defined in class path
> resource
> [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/mongo/MongoDatabaseFactoryDependentConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'gridFsTemplate'
> parameter 1; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate' available:
> expected single matching bean but found 2:
> mongoCountersTemplate,mongoDictionaryTemplate

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Use `@Qualifier` to inject by id.

Comment: to use qualifier I need to set it to bean. gridFsTemplate is an inner bean, I can't qualify mongo template beans in it